# A new notation for operations and some questions

Tags: notation, hyperoperation

let $x^{/1/}=x+x$ (addition)

$x^{/2/}=x.x$ (multiplication)

$x^{/3/}=x^x$ (exponentiation)

$x^{/4/}={}^xx$ (tetration)

and so on.....

I have the following questions:

> $(1)$ Can we define an operation between two known operations (Ex.addition and multiplication), where $n$ in $x^{/n/}$ is fractional (Ex. $x^{/1.5/}$)?
>
> $(2)$ Is there a closed form for $x^{/x/}$?
>
> $(3)$ Is infinitation ($x^{/\infty/}$) equal to infinite tetration $\left( x^{x^{x...}}\right)$?

I think the answer to the last question is true as infinite tetration is equal to infinite pentation (as both of them equal to $x^{x^{x^{.^{.^.}}}}$ when we convert them to their exponentiation form.) Following the same logic, any $n$-ation is equal to $x^{x^{x^{.^{.^.}}}}$, and therefore infiniation is also equal to infinite tetration.

Edit: Does this notation seem useful for defining operations?

Comment: In case you weren't aware https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation seems similar. Not sure about any of the questions though honestly.

Comment: Regarding 3, why would it be equal to infinite tetration and not to infinite addition, multiplication or exponentiation?

Comment: @xmq i am aware of Knuth up arrow notation, but it has its limitations. Ex. You cannot represent iterated addition with Knuth up arrow notation.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz as i have written in my question, any infinite $n$-ation can be represented as infinite tetration.

Comment: These definitions don't make sense if $x$ is non-integer, so you might adapt the more general notation of hyperoperations (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation). In this notation, $a^{/n/}=a[n+1]2$. Your claim about infinite tetration and infinite pentation is vague and informal. You should note that infinite tetration is the limit of $x[4]n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, whereas $x^{/\infty/}$ is the limit of $a[n+1]2$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so these are *completely* different and inspection of the latter seems to suggest it rapidly diverges either way.

Comment: @Thorgott that is exactly the motivation behind my question. Is there some way to define these fractional operations. If not then why can't we try to develop a new way to define this?

Comment: @Thorgott Also infinite tetration converges for $e^{-1} \lt x \le e^{1/e}$

Comment: I'm aware infinite tetration converges for these values. The entire point of my comment was that infinitation and infinite tetration are *completely* different beasts and that infinitation is rapidly divergent (except for the $x=1$ case), so the answer to $(3)$ is negative. Your comment on why you suspect them to be equal suggests you might be misunderstanding these recursions. As for the other question, you can definitely try; the difficulty is making such an extension meaningful. This seems to be very difficult and I certainly have no approach to do so, nor have I heard of one.

Comment: $(1)$ is a dupe of [Continuum between addition, multiplication and exponentiation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1269643) $(2)$ is ill-defined. What does "closed form" mean? Most standard meanings would classify your $x^{/4/}$ as having no closed form. And for $(3)$, I see no reason for it to be true at all, aside from the case of $x=1$. If one excludes $x=1$, then either it is never true, or you have to actually define what this is supposed to mean when $x$ is not an integer.

Comment: @Thorgott Infinitation is not divergent for all $x \neq 1$. For example, it seems that $2 \mathbin{[\infty]} 2 = 4$ and $0 \mathbin{[\infty]} 0 = 1$. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The [standard notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) for your $x^{/n/}$ is $H_n(x, x)$.

> (3) Is infinitation ($x^{/\infty/}$) equal to infinite tetration $\left( x^{x^{x...}}\right)$?

You're asking whether $H_\infty(x, x) = H_4(x, \infty)$. The answer is no. [Notice that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation#Special_cases)

\begin{align*}
    H_n(a, -1) &= 0 & n \geq 4 \\ 
    H_n(a, 0) &= 1 & n \geq 3 \\ 
    H_n(a, 1) &= a & n \geq 2 \\
    H_n(2, 2) &= 4 & n \geq 1
\end{align*}

Therefore
\begin{align*}
    H_\infty(-1, -1) &= 0 \\
    H_\infty(0, 0) &= 1 \\
    H_\infty(1, 1) &= 1 \\
    H_\infty(2, 2) &= 4
\end{align*}

But
\begin{align*}
    H_4(-1, \infty) &= -1 \\
    H_4(0, \infty) &= \frac{1}{2} & \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} H_4(\varepsilon, b) \\
    H_4(1, \infty) &= 1 \\
    H_4(2, \infty) & \quad \text{diverges}
\end{align*}

so they disagree at 3 of these 4 points.

> $(1)$ Can we define an operation between two known operations (Ex.addition and multiplication), where $n$ in $x^{/n/}$ is fractional (Ex. $x^{/1.5/}$)?

The names typically given to $H_{0.5}$ and $H_{1.5}$ are "halfation" and "sesquation", though there's little information about them.

Comment: So does $H_{\infty}(x,x)$ only converge only $x=-1, 0, 1, 2$? If not then could you tell me it's radius of convergence?